# Running Noir web framework at port 80

Tags: clojure, port

[Meta notes: the following question is not answered, but the problem that the question is involved in is considered solved. Thanks to @georgek]

I am experimenting [`Noir`](http://www.webnoir.org/) web framework on a home machine running Ubuntu linux. I followed the [`"Getting started"`](http://www.webnoir.org/#started) part from the Noir site and got the demo server up and running. But that example was running at the testing `port 8080`. I wanted it to run at the default http port (port 80), so I edited the `"8080"` part of the clojure file `my-website/src/my_website/server.clj`:

```
(ns my-website.server
  (:require [noir.server :as server]))

(server/load-views "src/my_website/views/")

(defn -main [& m]
  (let [mode (keyword (or (first m) :dev))
        port (Integer. (get (System/getenv) "PORT" "80"))] ; <- I changed "8080" to "80"
    (server/start port {:mode mode
                        :ns 'my-website})))
```

And tried to run the demo again, but I got the following:

```
$ lein run
Starting server...
2011-11-27 13:26:27.183:INFO::Logging to STDERR via org.mortbay.log.StdErrLog
2011-11-27 13:26:27.189:INFO::jetty-6.1.25
2011-11-27 13:26:27.242:WARN::failed SocketConnector@0.0.0.0:80: java.net.BindException: Permission denied
2011-11-27 13:26:27.242:WARN::failed Server@111ded2: java.net.BindException: Permission denied
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.BindException: Permission denied
    at clojure.lang.Util.runtimeException(Util.java:165)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6476)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6455)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6431)
    at clojure.core$eval.invoke(core.clj:2795)
    at clojure.main$eval_opt.invoke(main.clj:296)
...
...
```

I have root access to the machine, I just don't know where to start to solve this problem. Could anybody help?

---

**What I have tried:**

I tried to run `lein run` as `su`, but it didn't work either.

---

I stopped the Apache2 server for releasing port 80 (Is this the right way to do it?):

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 stop
```

Still doesn't work.

---

I did it all over again on a macbook, it worked for port 80 ("sudo" is needed). Don't know why it doesn't work for Ubuntu.

---

**The solution that I took**

A practical solution to the problem (not an answer to the question):

I followed [`this`](http://www.askapache.com/web-hosting/reverse-proxy-apache.html#Reverse_Proxy_Scenario) web page, and used 8080 port as a service, and then configured the "httpd.conf" file of the Apache2 server to let port 8080 listen all the requests to port 80. This solution is provided by @georgek .

[I am sorry if this post is not valuable to some people, I'm new in this field. Thank you again everyone!]

---

**An alternative solution**

@ivant provides an alternative solution which also works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend running Noir as a non-root user on 8080 and using a rule to forward that domain and port to your Apache running on 80. Is there another reason you don't want to do that?

Comment: Could you elaborate on this? I have forwarded both port 80 and port 8080 to the machine running Ubuntu with Apache installed. What should I do next, please?

Comment: Apologies, 'forward' might give the wrong idea here. I don't use Apache, but in nginx for example, in your configuration file you can write a rule such that when your web server receives a request on domain.com it'll send the request to port 8080, where your Noir would be listening. I think looking up 'reverse proxy apache' might help you out here.

Comment: I edited the configure file under /etc/apache2/sites-available. In the "VirtualHost *:80" container, I added "Redirect 301 / http://mysite.com:8080/". Now, when I type in the browser "mysite.com", I get the page I desired, but the url is ugly -- "mysite.com:8080".

Comment: I did a quick search and this seems like a good explanation of what you want, http://blog.lundscape.com/2009/05/configure-a-reverse-proxy-with-apache/

Comment: Thank you, georgek! Looking up 'reverse proxy apache' helps.

Answer (score 4):

Only root can use ports lower than 1024. If you say you tried running it as root or with sudo and still didn't work then most probably port 80 is already in use by some other application.

LE: This should show you which process is using the port 80

```
ps -eo pid,user,group,args,etime,lstart | grep `lsof -i :80 | grep LISTEN | head -1 | cut -f4 -d' '`
```

Comment: I got the usage direction by running the command above. I'm not sure how to fix it, there could be something wrong with the 'grep' part.

Comment: I used the command above on a Mac so maybe it doesn't work the same on your Ubuntu box. Try to run them separately: https://gist.github.com/1398068

Comment: Thank you, but for the first line of the commands, nothing returned. So, I assume nothing is using port 80.

Answer (score 2):

There is also [privbind](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/man1/privbind.1.html) and [authbind](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/en/man1/authbind.1.html), which grant the privilege to bind to low ports (< 1024) to non-root apps.  They are both available in ubuntu and may be a viable alternative to apache, especially while developing. To install (both) use the following:

```
$ sudo apt-get install privbind authbind
```

and check the man pages for usage instructions.

P.S. I know I'm a bit late for the party, but thought that these might still be useful.

Comment: This is very helpful. People see this will learn something new if they don't already know. Thank you! The party keeps going, that is part of the spirit of community.